# Question about the Bayesian Inference of a parameter

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, bayesian

In order to understand the difference between the Frequentist and Bayesian inference, I was reading the presentation at: http://www.stat.ufl.edu/archived/casella/Talks/BayesRefresher.pdf . In order to explain the difference between the approaches, the author is using the following example(Page 6): If I understand correctly, there are three different cases of protocols (something related to toxicity, it seems) and there are different studies for each of the three protocols, which has examined the relation of the protocol to a specific cause, which is called something as "AAN".

For example, for one of the three protocols, different studies showing the total number of cases (first) and relation to "AAN" (second) is as following :

1) 66,11

2) 1756,129

3) 272, 48

4) 151, 18

... etc. Each of these number pairs belong to different studies.

Now, the Bayesian model for these studies are given as such:

Given $X_j$ is the AAN frequency of the $j$th study about the protocol $i$, $X_j$ is distributed as $X_j \sim Binomial(n_j,p_i)$. $n_j$ is the total number of incidences for the $j$th study and $p_i$ is the parameter of the distribution we want to infer.

What I did not understand here is, the author says that, in this model $p_i$ can vary from study to study.

In my understanding of the Bayesian approach, here, all of the studies constitute our data, $D=\left( n_1,X_1,n_2,X_2,\ldots,n_K,X_K \right)$ where $K$ is the total number of studies. For $p_i$ we have a prior distribution of $P(p_i)$. So we try to find the posterior distribution $P(p_i\mid D)$. In my understanding $p_i$ cannot vary from study to study: $p_i$ is first generated from the prior distribution as $p_i \sim P(p_i)$ and then this generated value of $p_i$ is used to generate each $X_j \sim Binomial(n_j,p_i)$. Yes, $p_i$ is not fixed as in the frequentist approach, but it varies over different realizations of all $K$ studies, once a $p_i$ is generated from the prior, then all $K$ studies use the same $p_i$. So, it should not change from a single study to another. So, this slide has confused me at this particular point. Am I right with my thoughts here or did I misunderstand something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In the example, there are three protocols.  In the Bayesian viewpoint, the idea is that the number of events of interest is a binomial random variable whose probability of "success" is itself a random variable $p_i$.

Specific realizations of the data may be drawn from realizations of the underlying random variables in the model, but that does not mean that once those data are observed, the model parameters are fixed.

Perhaps an easier example is needed to illustrate this.  Suppose I show you a coin and you are interested in some sort of statistical inference about whether the coin is biased in some way.  Under the frequentist viewpoint, you would then want to take a sample and conduct a hypothesis test of the form $$H_0 : p = 0.5 \quad \mathrm{vs.} \quad H_a : p \ne 0.5$$ where $p$ is a **fixed parameter** that represents the probability that an individual toss of the coin will yield heads.  You can pick a significance level $\alpha$, say $0.01$, which represents the maximum Type I error probability you are willing to tolerate--i.e., the probability you incorrectly infer that the coin is biased when in fact it is fair, purely due to random chance, must not exceed 1%.  You can also set the power; say, you want $1-\beta = 0.9$; that is, you want your test to be able to detect if the coin is truly biased at least 90% of the time.  From these criteria, you can calculate the necessary sample size assuming that the coin is fair, and you would conduct your experiment, calculate your test statistic, and arrive at a conclusion about $p$.  Throughout, you assume that $p$ is a fixed but unknown parameter, and that sample you take is a specific realization of a random process that reflects the true value of this parameter.

Under a Bayesian viewpoint, you would impose a prior distribution on $p$; say, you could use a Jeffreys prior or a uniform prior, or a beta prior with specific hyperparameters if you have reason to believe that the coin is more likely to be biased in one way than another.  You take a sample as before, but this time, you regard the sample as fixed data that represents information that updates your prior belief about how $p$ is distributed; i.e., in light of this data, you calculate a posterior distribution for $p$, conditional on what was observed.  This posterior can then be turned into a credible interval, which tells you something about how likely $p$ is in a particular range of values.  The more data you observe, the more information you have with which to update your belief about $p$, and the narrower this credible interval (hopefully) becomes.  One way to make a "frequentist-style" inference about the biasedness of $p$ is to say that if the credible interval does not contain $0.5$, then you would conclude the coin is biased.  But for the Bayesian, it is the entire posterior distribution that captures your belief about $p$, because as we have already discussed, $p$ **is a random variable**--it is not fixed.

While this notion of the probability of a single coin toss yields heads as a random variable seems counterintuitive on its face, it is no more so than the random observations of the outcome of the coin itself:  that is what Casella is saying when he mentions that the frequentist regards the data as random and the parameter as fixed, whereas the Bayesian regards the data as fixed and the parameter as random.  To a Bayesian, the outcomes are what they are.  You *saw* them and it's a done deal.  Given that information, you are free to adjust your belief about $p$.  And why not?  It is not necessarily the case that $p$ needs to be an immutable quantity for all time.  Indeed, in many random processes, interpreting the underlying parameter(s) as fixed may not be a sensible assumption.

So, back to Casella's example.  Say under the first protocol, you observe the data he gives in the table.  The data is fixed, and it updates the prior distribution to a posterior distribution about $p_1$.  That doesn't mean each $X_j$ for the first protocol shares the same $p_1$.  Instead, it means that each $X_j$ for the first protocol shares the same *posterior distribution* for $p_1$.  The more studies you do under the first protocol, the more information you have about this posterior, and you may become more *certain* about the behavior of this random variable, but it is nevertheless random.  You can use the posterior of $p_1$ to generate a **posterior predictive distribution** on $X_{j(\mathrm{new})}$, that is to say, based on your updated knowledge of $p_1$, you can model the distribution of the number of events of interest observed for a hypothetical new study.

Comment: I get more confused. Let's keep with the simple coin example you have given. We want to infer whether the coin is biased or not. In the Bayesian view, $p$ is a random variable, I am completely OK with that. We have a prior distribution on $p$, let's call it $P(p)$. Suppose that we have observed $N$ coin tosses $x_1,x_2,...,x_N$ and we assume that these tosses are independent, given $p$. So, the posterior probability $P(p|x_{1:N})$ becomes proportional to $P(p)\prod_{i=1}^{N}P(x_i|p)$.

Comment: Thinking this as a generative process, $p$ comes from the prior distribution at the start and then the $N$ coin tosses use the same $p$. Then we can build the credible interval on the posterior distribution $P(p|x_{1:N})$. This is a sample of the Bayesian inference, isn't that right? If this is right, I did not get what is different in Casella's example about protocols and studies compared to this coin example. Isn't the posterior distribution for Casella's example $P(p_1|X_1,n_1,...,X_K,n_K)$? If it is so, how come we have different $p_1$s for each $X_j$?

Comment: See, the beginning of your second comment is where your misunderstanding lies: each realization of a coin toss does not involve generating a specific realization of a $p$, because the posterior distribution collapses.  The posterior distribution is obtained by computing the normalized likelihood over the entire support of $p$.  That each $\Pr[X_i \mid p]$ are calculated with the same $p$ simply represents the joint probability of obtaining the sample given the prior probability $p$.  This results in a posterior probability of $p$ given the data. (continued)

Comment: Then, if you want to realize a *new* coin toss, you use the posterior predictive distribution, which is calculated using information from the **entire** posterior distribution on $p$.

Comment: In other words, $\Pr[p \mid x_{1:N}]$ is a *function* of $p$, given the fixed data that was observed, that reflects in some sense the probability that the parameter equals $p$ given the data.  But under this model, the individual $X_j$ that were observed did not necessarily come from a process with the same $p_1$.  They were assumed to come from a process with the same **prior distribution** on $p_1$, because $p_1$ is a random variable.

Comment: Let's consider the graphical model at: http://imgur.com/rP0wbJI This simple graph encodes what I want to tell with my version of the coin example, the graph encodes the joint probability: $P(x_1,x_2,x_3,p) = P(x_1|p)P(x_2|p)P(x_3|p)P(p)$. In this model, let's say we have only observed $x_1,x_2,x_3$. The posterior distribution for $p$ is $P(p|x_1,x_2,x_3) \propto P(p)\prod_{i=1}^{3}P(x_i|p)$. Then, when we want to guess a new $x_4$ then it is: $P(x_4|x_1,x_2,x_3) = \sum_p P(x_4|p)P(p|x_1,x_2,x_3)$. I think this is the what you refer to posterior predictive distribution. Is all that right?

Comment: That is correct, except that because $p$ is a continuous random variable on $[0,1]$, the sum over $p$ should be an integral:  $$\Pr[x_4 \mid x_1, x_2, x_3] = \int_{p=0}^1 \Pr[X_4 \mid p] f(p \mid x_1, x_2, x_3) \, dp.$$  Note that this integral is essentially a weighted average over all $p$, weighted by the likelihood of observing $p$ given the previous data $x_1, x_2, x_3$.

Comment: Ok, then based upon that model, what I wanted to tell was that: I interpret this model, such that for each single realization of $p$ in the range $[0,1]$, we observe coin tosses $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ from $P(x_1|p)$, $P(x_2|p)$ and $P(x_3|p)$. For a single realization of $p$, the three coin tosses use the same value of $p$. But we have infinitely many such $p$ realizations and I am well aware that in the posterior predictive distribution, we use the likelihood of observing each realization of $p$ giving the fixed data $x_1,x_2,x_3$.

Comment: Casella's example gives the impression that for each study $X_j$ which is analogous to our single coin flips, that there are different $p_i$ values, which differs from study to study. In our coin example this would correspond to $P(x_1|p_1)$, $P(x_2|p_2)$ and $P(x_3|p_3)$. Then this would be equivalent to that we are tossing three different coins which would be, expectedly, completely independent from another. This is what I am trying to explain.

Comment: Using the same $p$ for each $x_1, x_2, x_3$ in the conditional probability doesn't mean that those observed data were actually generated using that value of $p$.  It is done this way to obtain a **likelihood** of having seen the data you saw, *assuming* that the parameter has value $p$.  The observed data $x_1, x_2, x_3$ came from a model for which the underlying parameter of success is **random** and therefore it **IS** different for **each** observation.

Comment: In other words, $\Pr[x_i \mid p]$ is the conditional probability of observing $x_i$ given $p$, but it doesn't mean that $x_i$ was actually **generated** using such a value of $p$.  That is the essence of the confusion.

Comment: Well, but this contradicts with what I have learned about Bayesian Statistics until now. If the model encodes the joint probability $P(x_1, x_2, x_3, p)$ this tells to me that we have a probability measure for each possible 4-tuple of $ x_1, x_2, x_3, p $. We have four random variables in this system and and each outcome is a four dimensional vector. I cannot fit what you are saying in this view...

Comment: Yet you don't have any problem interpreting a posterior predictive distribution as not coming from a fixed parameter $p$?  If you generate an $x_4$ from previous data $x_1, x_2, x_3$, what was the $p$ that generated it?  The answer is that there is *no* such single point value $p$--the probability distribution for $x_4 \mid x_1, x_2, x_3$ is calculated by integrating over all $p$.  Now say you generate $x_5$ from $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$.  Can you say that those four previous values were calculated from a single common realization of $p$?

Comment: Ah, I think I see your point. You say that, when what we know about the world is only the observations $x_1,x_2,x_3$, then we cannot be sure what $p$ is pointwise. Then the best thing we could do would be integrating over all possible $p$, like a weighted average, which is $P(x_4|x_1,x_2,x_3) = \int_{p=0}^{1}P(x_4|p)P(p|x_1,x_2,x_3)dp$. I don't have any problem with that because this is the broadest inference we can do what we have at hand. But I tend to think the generation process like this (continued)

Comment: Let's say there is a sample space $\Omega$ which has all possible outcomes for $(p,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$. Then one of these infinitely many outcomes, $\omega$ is selected. This is where the randomness occurs. The outcome is fixed before we begin to observe any of the variables. We don't know and will not know ever what the value of $p$ is in this outcome $\omega$, but we can build a posterior probability distribution for it as we observe new $x_i$ and then we can infer the value of $x_{i+1}$ by building posterior predictive distribution, assuming we know the prior $P(p)$.

Comment: There is this sentence ,n the wikipedia article about "Probability Space" stating that: "Once the probability space is established, it is assumed that “nature” makes its move and selects a single outcome, ω, from the sample space Ω. All the events in $\mathcal{F}$ that contain the selected outcome ω (recall that each event is a subset of Ω) are said to “have occurred”." This is how my imagination about probabilistic processes works. I think our differences stem from this understanding of mine.